# Is WebAssembly going to replace JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic-programming, web-development-server, webassembly

It’s been 2 months I’ve been deeply studying JavaScript plus it’s libraries and frameworks. I’m hearing from other students in my high school telling me assembly will replace what JavaScript. Is this true?

And another question what language do you recommend for back end development close to JavaScript? I really do not want any to be a broke artist. I hear a lot that JavaScript developers get laid of and replaced since it’s just a annoying language to deal.

Comment: Don't believe everything you hear

Comment: Different tools for different jobs.

Answer (score 6):

WebAssembly cannot do anything in a Web embedding without JavaScript, and it wasn't in our design intent to replace JavaScript. It's even part of [the FAQ](http://webassembly.org/docs/faq/#is-webassembly-trying-to-replace-javascript)!

> No! WebAssembly is designed to be a complement to, not replacement of,
>   JavaScript. While WebAssembly will, over time, allow many languages to
>   be compiled to the Web, JavaScript has an incredible amount of
>   momentum and will remain the single, privileged (as described
>   [above](http://webassembly.org/docs/faq/#is-webassembly-only-for-cc-programmers)) dynamic
>   language of the Web. Furthermore, it is expected that JavaScript and
>   WebAssembly will be used together in a number of configurations:
>
> - Whole, compiled C++ apps that leverage JavaScript to glue things together.
> - HTML/CSS/JavaScript UI around a main WebAssembly-controlled center canvas,   allowing developers to leverage the power of web frameworks
>     to build   accessible, web-native-feeling experiences.
> - Mostly HTML/CSS/JavaScript app with a few high-performance WebAssembly modules   (e.g., graphing, simulation, image/sound/video
>     processing, visualization,   animation, compression, etc., examples
>     which we can already see in asm.js   today) allowing developers to
>     reuse popular WebAssembly libraries just like   JavaScript libraries
>     today.
> - When WebAssembly gains the ability to access garbage-collected objects,   those objects will be shared with
>     JavaScript, and not live in a walled-off   world of their own.

I would say that [WebAssembly is JavaScript's sidekick](https://webkit.org/blog/7691/webassembly/).

Comment: I have no idea what I am talking about here but… isn't the next release of WebAssembly supposed to allow it to communicate directly with the DOM? If that is true, when that happens, won’t you be able to bypass JavaScript completely? Also, once WebAssembly has access to the DOM, wouldn’t it be able to completely take over the page rendering process (draw its own textboxes comboboxes etc) allowing us to bypass the whole HTML/CSS/JavaScript disaster?

Comment: @T555 Yes, I believe it will, which means the only thing preventing JS being replaced by wasm is inertia.

Comment: @T555 Conceptually, WASM is almost what JVM is to Java. It's a type of code that can be run in modern web browsers which affords web apps major gains in performance. It's not primarily intended to be written by hand rather it's a compilation target for C, C++, Rust, etc. You don't have to know WASM code to take advantage of it rather you can import WASM modules exposing its API for use in JS. It would be VERY arcane to develop web apps in WASM considering the good paradigms, expressiveness and tool chain which HTML, CSS and JS has given us so far.

Comment: @T555 Going with the analogy above WASM isn't meant to take over the rendering process. The intricate process of building DOM and CSSOM; loading resources, parsing and executing JS is something that client apps do, and will likely remain a challenge of that layer on the web. I don't think WASM is trying to encroach that functionality.

Comment: Third, every language and platform has its fair share of disaster though in the case of the Web problems are aggravated by openness. Standards are anything less than perfect but when you consider adoption and implementation they're a less significant part of equation. We've struggled for decades with adoption; remember pre-IE 11 MS era, and Safari at some point. Shoddy implementation bequeathed us polyfills first jQuery and now the likes of core-js and friends. HTML and CSS endured hate, and recently love thanks to works like Transcending CSS, CSS Zen Garden and the rise of UX.